# Access Microsoft Face API IOS with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, azure, azure-cognitive-services, face

I am trying to enter to the API from Microsoft FACE API. I created an account on Azure and created the service that they provide me the keys.
The point is that I am trying to get access  to the API and it's all time a 401 error

```
let client = MPOFaceServiceClient(subscriptionKey: "MY_API_KEY")
```

All time returns the same error:

```
Error Domain=POFaceServiceClient error - http response is not success : 
                    {"error":{"code":"Unspecified","message":"Access denied due to invalid subscription key. Make sure you are subscribed to an API you are trying to call and provide the right key."}}
                         Code=401 "(null)"
```

There is no almost documentation for the API in IOS and then it's just objective-c, no swift. Can someone figure out why is this returning all time the 401 error???

Edit:
As well I tried  let client = `MPOFaceServiceClient(endPointAndSubscriptionKey: "MY_SERVER_AREA", key: "MY_API_KEY")`
but this one returns all time 404 error, resource was not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it.

For those who have the same problem, here it's the solution:

it worked for me just with `MPOFaceServiceClient(subscriptionKey: "MY_API_KEY")` and you MUST use the same endpoint as the example from the IOS SDK. We are talking about the WESTUS server. Just that one, nor Europe server, or WestUs2 server.It has to be WESTUS.

After that, my problem has gone and it worked perfectly.